# Where to put the call web service to feed Table View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios5

I'm callling a a webservice in the ViewDidLoad of a table view, to set the instance array categories that contains the values to be set in the cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

I detected that numberOfRowsInSection: is called before viewDidLoad, so array categories is still empty and no row is shown in the table.

Where I must call the web service?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once the webservice has finished loading you can call `[tableView reloadData];`.. this will refresh your table.. hoping this helps.

Answer (score 1):

try to call your webservice in `viewWillAppear` after get your data just reload your table view `[tableView reloadData];`

Comment: I won't advise this as this will call the webservice again and again everytime the view appears... viewDidLoad is the place to call the webservice.

Answer (score 0):

ok, you can define web servieses in any were in code mence if u want to used web service when press button then u do it, most important is that u used the [tableview reloadData] methode and one thing for sure that web service is return only "one" string, You should parse it by objectForKey method otherwise array has only one element and that's hole string